# how to prevent to start multiple startId In Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

I am using the following code and when I click on button I get multiple `startId` creations in service. Can somebody tell me how to prevent starting multiple `startId` In Android?

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
System.out.println(startId+ " == startId");
handler.postDelayed(this, 8000);
}
}, 8000); 

return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);}
```

This is the output that I'm getting:

```
03-09 02:39:14.128 18298-18298/com.simple.project I/System.out: 1 == startId

03-09 02:39:14.268 18298-18298/com.simple.project I/System.out: 2 == startId

03-09 02:39:14.449 18298-18298/com.simple.project I/System.out: 3 == startId

03-09 02:39:14.719 18298-18298/com.simple.project I/System.out: 4 == startId

03-09 02:39:15.059 18298-18298/com.simple.project I/System.out: 5 == startId

03-09 02:39:15.219 18298-18298/com.simple.project I/System.out: 6 == startId

03-09 02:39:15.409 18298-18298/com.simple.project I/System.out: 7 == startId

03-09 02:39:15.580 18298-18298/com.simple.project I/System.out: 8 == startId

03-09 02:39:15.740 18298-18298/com.simple.project I/System.out: 9 == startId

03-09 02:39:15.900 18298-18298/com.simple.project I/System.out: 10 == startId
```

Comment: Something is calling `startService()` repeatedly, every few 100 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

`startId` is precisely a **unique integer** representing this specific request to start.
It will increase on each invocation to `startService()`.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Should be a comment.

Comment: Mr Diego Torres Milano, Can You Give me a code ? I request to you please give me if possible

Comment: Don't know what you are asking for. You are calling `startService()` and that's the reason why it's increasing.